# javascript update the property value if not true inside array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Given the following object:

```
const kids = {
    name: 'john',
    extra: {
        city: 'London',
        hobbies: [
            {
                id: 'football',
                team: 'ABC',
                joined: true
            },
            {
                id: 'basketball',
                team: 'DEF',
                joined: false
            },
            {
                id: 'volleyball',
                team: 'DEF',
                joined: null
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

i want to update the `joined` field in every object of the hobbies array and set them to `null` if not `true`;

the question is how can i do it using map and find? and update the current variable and not create a new one.

Comment: OK..Good luck with that..

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the hobbies array and set default values for the joined field as null:

```js
const kids = {
    name: 'john',
    extra: {
        city: 'London',
        hobbies: [
            {
                id: 'football',
                team: 'ABC',
                joined: true
            },
            {
                id: 'basketball',
                team: 'DEF',
                joined: false
            },
            {
                id: 'volleyball',
                team: 'DEF',
                joined: null
            },
        ],
    },
};

kids.extra.hobbies.forEach(h => h.joined = h.joined || null);

console.log(kids);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array#forEach` for that. `find` is an overkill and `map` is really not required since you're not returning anything from the iteration.

```js
const kids = {
  name: 'john',
  extra: {
    city: 'London',
    hobbies: [{
        id: 'football',
        team: 'ABC',
        joined: true
      },
      {
        id: 'basketball',
        team: 'DEF',
        joined: false
      },
      {
        id: 'volleyball',
        team: 'DEF',
        joined: null
      },
    ],
  },
};

kids.extra.hobbies.forEach(item => {
  if (item.joined !== true) {
    item.joined = null
  }
})

console.log(kids);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Code:

```js
const kids = {name: 'john',extra: {city: 'London',hobbies: [{id: 'football',team: 'ABC',joined: true},{id: 'basketball',team: 'DEF',joined: false},{id: 'volleyball',team: 'DEF',joined: null},]}};
kids.extra.hobbies.forEach(hobby => hobby.joined = hobby.joined || null);

console.log(kids.extra.hobbies);
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code snippet show you how to do that. Just loop through the array and put an if statement.

```js
const kids = {
    name: 'john',
    extra: {
        city: 'London',
        hobbies: [
            {
                id: 'football',
                team: 'ABC',
                joined: true
            },
            {
                id: 'basketball',
                team: 'DEF',
                joined: false
            },
            {
                id: 'volleyball',
                team: 'DEF',
                joined: null
            },
        ],
    },
};
for(var i=0;i<kids.extra.hobbies.length;i++){
  var data = kids.extra.hobbies[i];
  if(data.joined !== true){
    data.joined = null;
  }
}
console.log(kids)
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `data,joined !== true`?   Otherwise "truthy" values would also pass.  And if that's OK, maybe just say `if (data.joined)` and skip the comparison altogether...

Answer (score 0):

Use array map and check if the value is false , then set it to null, map will return a new array. Then set it to kids.extra.hobbies

```js
const kids = {
  name: 'john',
  extra: {
    city: 'London',
    hobbies: [{
        id: 'football',
        team: 'ABC',
        joined: true
      },
      {
        id: 'basketball',
        team: 'DEF',
        joined: false
      },
      {
        id: 'volleyball',
        team: 'DEF',
        joined: null
      },
    ],
  },
};
var x = kids.extra.hobbies.map(function(item) {
  if (item.joined === false) {
    item.joined = null;
    return item
  } else {
    return item;
  }

})
kids.extra.hobbies = x;
console.log(kids)
```

Comment: I believe the OP wanted to modify the key-value pair _in place_, doesn't this replace the `hobbies` array?  I admit it's not super-clear from the question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(kids.extra.hobbies).each(function(){
            if(this.joined !== true){
                this.joined = null;
                alert(this.joined)
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Oh my bad. Sorry for the inconvenience.